# Joining 2 columns of a subqueried table into SQL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to match the inventory for the day to the SKU.
Amazon_orders has the SKUs I want to match
Invhistory2 has the SKU, timestamp date (more than 1, here's the issue), and the inventory quantity

I'm trying to create a subquery that averages the inventory for the day, then join the timestamp and SKU to the SKUs on the amazon orders table. Null values are no issue here.

My code looks like this:

```
(SELECT AVG(quantity) AS qty FROM `perfect-obelisk-289514.inventory_history.invhistory2`) AS qtyok

FROM `perfect-obelisk-289514.reports.flat_file_orders_by_order_datereport` Amazon_Orders

LEFT JOIN (SELECT AVG(quantity) AS qty, sku, CAST(snapshot_date AS DATE) AS invdate
FROM `perfect-obelisk-289514.inventory_history.invhistory2`
GROUP BY sku, invdate) AS table2
ON (
 Amazon_Orders.sku = table2.sku AND CAST(LEFT(Amazon_orders.purchase_date,10) AS DATE) = table2.invdate
 )
```

The issue is that I get the same average for each row, it's not joining the quantity using SKU and date.

As you may notice I'm a beginner, looked thoroughly but can't find the solution, any help is appreciated!

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  I also note that your question refers to `Table 1`, but the sample code has no such reference.  Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation would also help.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - Simplify! [mcve]

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I meant to shorten the real name for it to be more understandable

Comment: Just a hunch - but - is the snapshot timestamp identical to purchase date?

Comment: It is! Though one is string and one is timestamp, hence the cast function

Comment: Remove all doubt first ? - Cast both to identical values first - convert to string for testing - - start with just date format then add hour minute second ?  Still the same errors?

Comment: Now that I look closer you're right, I'm going to look into how to make them both match. Thanks!

Comment: I think my logic is off with the select part. I was able to now make the table give values but it gives me the same for all entries, how can I make it select the average per sku and date? I updated the code on the top

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help!
I managed to solve it. My code was redundant, I just needed this join:

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT AVG(quantity) AS qty, 

sku, 

CAST(snapshot_date AS DATE) AS invdate

FROM `perfect-obelisk-289514.inventory_history.invhistory2`

GROUP BY sku, invdate) AS table2

ON 
(Amazon_Orders.sku = table2.sku AND CAST(LEFT(Amazon_orders.purchase_date,10) AS DATE) = table2.invdate)
```

This gives me what I need